# elastic apm not showing graphql's lex/ parse/ validate time

Tags: graphql, nestjs, elastic-apm, nestjs-graphql

Currently, we are using the nestjs with Graphql,
we are able to show different spans in the execution phase,

For example: connecting redis/ db / external HTTP calls.

But is there a way to also show the time for `graphql.lex`, `graphql.parse`, `graphql.validate`...etc ?

Here is the screenshot I found from elastic apm github's readme, which shows it should be possible to do so.

https://github.com/elastic/apm/blob/main/specs/agents/tracing-instrumentation-graphql.md

[image]